# Why is AssertionError: assertion failed: Executor has not been attached to this receiver?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-streaming

I'm trying to build a simple spark streaming custom receiver where messages are stored directly in the spark stream in order to be processed. However I get:

> java.lang.AssertionError: assertion failed: Executor has not been attached to this receiver

I'm integrating into a third party java library that generates methods calls based on a socket it is listening to. By implementing an interface in the third party java library I plan to call the store method in the custom spark receiver.

I've created a simple cut down example which has the error, which does not reference the third party java library.

```
package com.custom.spark

import org.apache.spark.streaming.receiver.Receiver
import org.apache.spark.streaming.StreamingContext
import org.apache.spark.storage.StorageLevel
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.apache.spark.streaming.Seconds

object CustomSparkReceiver {

  def main(args: Array[String]) {

    // create stream with custom receiver
    val conf = new SparkConf().setMaster("local[*]").setAppName("CustomSparkReceiver")
    val ssc = new StreamingContext(conf, Seconds(1))      
    val customReceiver = new CustomReceiver
    val stream = ssc.receiverStream(customReceiver)

    // print values in spark stream
    stream.print

    // start pushing data into stream
    ssc.start
    Thread.sleep(1000)

    List.range(1, 10)
      .foreach { number => customReceiver.store(number) }

    Thread.sleep(1000)
    ssc.stop()      
  }

  class CustomReceiver extends Receiver[Integer](StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK_2) {  
    def onStart() = {}
    def onStop() = {}
  }
}
```

I think it is some sort of threading issue but not sure how to fix it. Any pointers on the above would be great.

Comment: hey mark, i am getting the same issue, 
you need to specify the source of messages in "onStart" method.
i believe that it might be cloning/changing the receiver object internally , and so you might not be able to use the same object ref.
btw, have you resolved this issue yet?